# how to completely remove cuda? (16.04)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

I was given a ubuntu 16.04 machine, and I think somebody had installed cuda 9.0 before. I installed cuda 10.1 using .deb file and then I installed tensorflow-gpu but found it requires which requires cuda 10.0 so I installed cuda-10.0 toolkit (toolkit only). by the way, I installed nvidia driver using apt-get install, (latest version).
Somehow, tensorflow-gpu doesn't work (only cpu is used), so I decided to completely remove cuda. I tried `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cuda` and when I type `dpkg -l | grep cuda`, I see

```
ii  cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48 1.0-1                                        amd64        cuda repository configuration files
ii  cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-nvjpeg-update-1 1.0-1                                        amd64        cuda repository configuration files
ii  libnccl-dev                                     2.2.13-1+cuda9.0                             amd64        NVIDIA Collectives Communication Library (NCCL) Development Files
ii  libnccl2                                        2.2.13-1+cuda9.0                             amd64        NVIDIA Collectives Communication Library (NCCL) Runtime
ii  nccl-repo-ubuntu1604-2.2.13-ga-cuda9.0          1-1                                          amd64        nccl repository configuration files
rc  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                             7.5.18-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
```

how can I remove those `cuda9.0` things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deinstall the packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge libnccl-dev libnccl2
```